# Changing Icloud user name

Tags: icloud

I have an Iphone 4s that is linked to an Icloud account with an old email account that I no longer have access to.  Is there a way to delete that old account and recreate  a new account with my new email address?

Comment: @KevinGrabher you **can** change your login email. Check: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202667

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with the Apple ID used to activate the iCloud Service. **An Apple ID is simply an email address** that you sign into Apple with and, by extension, use set up Apple’s auxilary services (iCloud, iTunes Store Purchases, etc).

> Is there a way to delete that old account?

Apple usually won’t let you delete an old Apple ID. You need to [contact Apple ID Support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT5699) to inquire. If you wish to purge Apple’s servers of all the information associated with that Apple ID, [you can.](http://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac/how-remove-your-apple-id-completely-shut-down-your-itunes-store-icloud-other-accounts-3474388/)

> Is there a way to…recreate a new account with my new email address?

Yes.

### Option One:

**[Create a new Apple ID](https://appleid.apple.com/account)** using your new email address. This is the easiest solution.

### Option Two:

Change the primary email address associated with your Apple ID account. You don’t need access to the old email address in order to change your Apple ID. This is preferable if you have old purchases or other information you wish to keep.* **[From Apple ID FAQ:](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT5622)**

> **I no longer have an email address that was also my Apple ID. Can I still use the email address as my Apple ID?**
>
> Apple recommends you change your Apple ID to your current, working email address. This will not create another Apple ID, it will only
>   change it to your working email address. See [Changing the name you use
>   for your Apple ID](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202667) if you'd like more information.

*It’s important to note that you cannot merge Apple IDs. Period (period).

Comment: Just a comment on option 1: you will lose associated purchases, Game Center achievements, contacts, calendar, emails, etc.

Answer (score 0):

First step, turn off FindMyiPhone if it's on.  (you don't have to but it will be easier)
then go to appleid.apple.com and click "Manage Apple Id".  Now go back to the iPhone and change the login's for iCloud, iTunes and Appstore, Facetime, Messages and Game Center.  Turn find my iPhone back on anytime after you change the iCloud login.

Answer (score 0):

Just been through torture trying to turn off 'find my iphone' and delete things.  Fact is, because I foolishly changed my icloud login on my mac before doing the other devices,  it would simply not let me past the old (now defunct) login email address.  So:   I connected my iphone to itunes using my USB lead and went into backup.  First question asked by the machine:  'this iphone is sync'd to another itunes account, do you want to change?   I answered 'Yes' and the problem seemed to go away.  Hope this helps.